# Sp for calculating AvgBal and End Bal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrKxL.jpg)

Write a procedure to pass input parameter as MM-YYYY and cname 
and find the Avg Bal as well as End Bal.

Write a procedure to pass input parameter as MM-YYYY and cname 
and find the Avg Bal as well as End Bal.

Business Rules:

-- Consider two tables Dim_date and Fct_DD.
-- In Dim_date table  take hol_flag in that if sunday will come pass that as 'Y' else pass Flag value as 'N'
-- Take sunday bal as saturday bal only.
-- End bal means Total bal left at the end of month.

Can any one help me i don't know how to do.
Thanks

This is my code

```
Create proc sp_AvgBal_End_Bal
(
    @MMYY varchar(20),
    @Cname varchar(20)
)

as
begin

declare @Sdate date,
        @Edate date,
        @Avg_Bal int,
        @End_Bal int

set @Sdate=convert(date,('01-'+@MMYY))
set @Edate=EOMONTH(@Sdate)

while (@Sdate<=@Edate)
begin
if (datename(dw,@Edate))='Sunday'
```

Comment: Contrary to what you have heard, Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.  In general, you only get help if you have tried something and have gotten stuck at a legitimate spot.  At the very least, you should include your sample data directly in the question, and then show us what SQL code you have tried.

Comment: I traied but i didn't get idea how to do

Comment: And what does the script you have now, do?